# Postman gives l:SSLV3_ALERT_CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN:../../../../src/third_party/boringssl/src/ssl/tls_record.cc:594:SSL alert number 46

Tags: ssl, curl, https, postman, ssl-client-authentication

I have an endpoint which is secured with client authentication(HTTPS).
To test that locally, i have my own certificate signed my own CA(test, I followed this guide to create test cert and test CA [2]). I have imported cert and root ca to certificates store and trust store. My cert has been assigned with client certificate authentication along with signing, encryption usecases.

Also, in postman  im passinc CA certificate with the client certificate and passphrase. (I tried p12 format and *.crt format). I disabled SSL verification option also.

But when I send the request postman gives following error[1];

[1]

```
Error: write EPROTO 67845640:error:10000416:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:SSLV3_ALERT_CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN:../../../../src/third_party/boringssl/src/ssl/tls_record.cc:594:SSL alert number 46
```

Request is not hitting the endpoint. (I don't see any server level logs). Postman logs says, client cert is passed with request body with above error.

May I know, why this occurs?

Also I tried with curl different options setup; But no luck. Same error

```
#curl  --cacert ratha-root-CA.pem --cert ratha-testlocal.crt --key ratha-root-private.key  https://XXXXXXX --ssl-revoke-best-effort --verbose

* schannel: disabled automatic use of client certificate
* schannel: Failed to import cert file ratha-testlocal.crt, last error is 0x80092002
* Closing connection 0
curl: (58) schannel: Failed to import cert file ratha-testlocal.crt, last error is 0x80092002
```

[2]https://deliciousbrains.com/ssl-certificate-authority-for-local-https-development/

p.s:Im using windows 10 machine with latest versions of the tool

Answer (score 1):

Meta: I'm not convinced this is programming or development, but I need space and formatting. I agree to deleting this if the Q is voted closed.

> ... postman gives ... 10000416:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:SSLV3_ALERT_CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN
> Request is not hitting the endpoint. (I don't see any server level logs).

This is literally true, but the error IS from the server = your endpoint. The way HTTPS works is the client, here postman, connects to the server, here endpoint; the two systems then start an SSL/TLS session using a fairly complicated 'handshake' process; and finally the client sends the HTTP request to the server within the SSL/TLS session. This error is occurring before the handshake completes and thus before the request is sent, hence no logged request, but postman *did* connect to the server and send the certificate as part of the handshake, and the server rejected it.

The relevant question is why; alert 46 covers many possible cases. If the server has any other log(s) (like apache usually has separate access_log and error_log) check it/them. If not, looking very carefully at the certs you generated and understanding how they should work may help. There are two possibilities that spring out at me:

- the webpage you followed is intended for creating a *server* cert, not a client cert. While the actual generating in openssl can be the same, the way you trust the result may be different, and in particular depends critically on what the server (endpoint) software is -- apache? nginx? haproxy? IIS? Tomcat/Wildfly? nodejs/express? etc? etc?
- the statement in that webpage that the (subject) Distinguished Name for the server (or other end-entity such as your client) "don’t matter" is dangerously incomplete. It doesn't matter exactly what the DN is, but it does matter what it is NOT: it must NOT be identical to the DN of the CA cert, as the example given *almost* but not quite is (it differs only in the email address).

  As an aside: unlike an SSL/TLS server cert, which absolutely does need the SubjectAltName (SAN) extension as stated there, an SSL/TLS client cert does not. However, having it unnecessarily present *shouldn't* be a problem.

If your problem isn't indicated by the server log(s) or one of those obvious ones, I would first try replacing the server with the test tool `openssl s_server` using this cert-and-key (and `-www` so that a requester like postman can get a valid response) and see if that works: if so, the problem must be your server (endpoint); if not, we know it's the cert(s) and need to look at it/them in detail.

> Also I tried with curl ... Same error
> curl: (58) schannel: Failed to import cert file ratha-testlocal.crt, last error is 0x80092002

That's not the same error at all. *Many* variants of curl, especially on Linux, use OpenSSL, and can use for `--cert` and `--key` the files created by OpenSSL -- though in that case you should use the entity cert and *entity* key, not the root key. However curl can use other protocol libraries, and your variant, apparently the one supplied by Microsoft for Windows 10 up, uses schannel instead of OpenSSL, so it cannot use these files for a client cert-and-key, instead it must use an entry in the Windows cert store, usually the 'MY' section (shown as 'Personal' in MMC/certmgr). See [the man page](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-E) . If you did put your cert-and-key in the cert store and reference it there, you should get a similar error from curl as from postman, but not quite the same, because schannel generally provides less detail about errors than OpenSSL does.

Comment: I fixed it by redoing everything. Im not sure which step fixed the issue..But when I regenerate the certificate I added extendedKeyUsage= clientAuth parameter. Earlier I added that under keyUsage param  ..I think there was a warning about that..That may be the root cause for the issue got resolved it

Comment: Regarding, curl I think yes it is windows 10 tool..That never got fixed even with the new cert which is imported to certstore and root cert to truststore